# Search a string data on Stack

Tags: java, stack

Im doing my project and I must doing search on stack. If new element is exist on stack, It wont push, else it will push.
But I dont know how can I write my own search code( stack.search is banned so I must write my own one).Im openminded to all tips/tricks. Thanks :)

My code is here by the way :)

```
  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return first == null;
}

/**
 * Returns the number of items in this stack.
 *
 * @return the number of items in this stack
 */
public int size() {
    return n;
}

/**
 * Adds the item to this stack.
 *
 * @param  item the item to add
 */
public void push(Item item) {
    Node<Item> oldfirst = first;
    first = new Node<Item>();
    first.item = item;
    first.next = oldfirst;
    n++;
}

/**
 * Removes and returns the item most recently added to this stack.
 *
 * @return the item most recently added
 * @throws NoSuchElementException if this stack is empty
 */
public Item pop() {
    if (isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException("Stack underflow");
    Item item = first.item;        // save item to return
    first = first.next;            // delete first node
    n--;
    return item;                   // return the saved item
}


/**
 * Returns (but does not remove) the item most recently added to this stack.
 *
 * @return the item most recently added to this stack
 * @throws NoSuchElementException if this stack is empty
 */
public Item peek() {
    if (isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException("Stack underflow");
    return first.item;
}

/**
 * Returns a string representation of this stack.
 *
 * @return the sequence of items in this stack in LIFO order, separated by spaces
 */
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for (Item item : this) {
        s.append(item);
        s.append(' ');
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```

Comment: You have shown only the partial code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is just traverse the stack. It will be done in a linear time.

```
for(Item obj : stack)
{
    // Do whatever processing you require
    System.out.println(obj);
}
```